# insert list data to table with Python

Tags: python, postgresql

here is a function which allows to insert a list of data in a table in PostgreSQL

```
def importYear(year):
  go = True
  if isAlreadyInserted(year):
    if replace == False:
      print("donnees pour annee " + year + " deja inserees, action annulee")
      go = False
    else:
      print("donnees pour annee " + year + " deja inserees, les donnees seront remplacees")
      deleteData(year)

  if go:
    data_to_insert = getDataToInsert(data)
    print(data_to_insert)
    SQLrequest = "INSERT INTO pru_data (date1, day, area, type, act, dir, ach) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    try:
        execute_values(conn.cursor(), SQLrequest)
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        with psycopg2.connect(connString) as conn:    # Ouverture connexion a la base
          with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute(SQLrequest)
            cur.execute("COMMIT")
            cur.close()
        return 1
    print( "Record inserted successfully into table")
```

I got this error :

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « % »
LINE 1: ..., type, act, dir, ach) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%...
```

`data_to_insert` is a list not dataframe

Thank's for your help

Comment: Read the docs here [Execute Values](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html?highlight=execute_values#psycopg2.extras.execute_values)

Comment: thank's for your help

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
if go:
    data_to_insert = getDataToInsert(data)
    print(len(data_to_insert) - 1)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_to_insert, columns=['date1','day','area','type','act','dir','ach'])
    for column in df:
        df['hfe_type'] = df['hfe_type'].replace([None],"None")
    # Create a list of tupples from the dataframe values
    tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_numpy()]
    # Comma-separated dataframe columns
    cols = ','.join(list(df.columns))
    print(cols)
    # SQL quert to execute
    query  = "INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES %%s" % ('table', cols)
    # cursor = conn.cursor()
    cur = None
    connection_bis = psycopg2.connect(
        host="ukbar.per.ath",
        database="indicateurs_per",
        user="per",
    )
    connection_bis.autocommit = True
    cursor = connection_bis.cursor()
    try:
        extras.execute_values(cursor, query, tuples)
        # conn.commit()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("Error: %s" % error)
        connection_bis.rollback()
        cursor.close()
        return 1
    print("execute_values() done")
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: You don't want to do this:`query  = "INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES %%s" % ('table', cols)`. See here [Dynamic SQL](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) for proper way to build a dynamic query string.